# How to track checks in checkedListBox C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, checkedlistbox

I try to display the number of checked items in the checkedListBox: `checkedListBox1.CheckedIndices.Count`
But how can i update my count, if i want to display it on label? I tried to write all in the ItemCheck event:

```
private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {            
        label1.Text= checkedListBox1.CheckedIndices.Count;
    }
```

But the count increases even if i uncheck the item :(
I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add one or subtract one depending on the `e.NewValue==CheckState.Checked`

Comment: It doesn't give an error, but it doesn't work either... Same behavior as with `CheckedIndices`. The count isn't updated at the time when we check the count..

Comment: Just add one or subtract one depending on the `e.NewValue==CheckState.Checked`.

Comment: thank you, it works! if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
                checks++;
            else if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Unchecked)
                checks--;

Comment: Great! Simple is best! But the answer is in the comments, not the answer itself! Please edit the answer and put the correct solution.

Comment: Fixing the answer itself, because as it currently stands it doesn't answer the question at all.

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation for `CheckedListBox.ItemCheck`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.itemcheck.aspx) event states that:

> The check state is not updated until after the ItemCheck event occurs.

so when the event is called, the `CheckedIndices.Count` is not yet updated. To overcome this, you have to subclass the `CheckedListBox` class and fire a new event *after* the [`CheckedListBox.ItemCheck`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.itemcheck.aspx) event:

```
public class MyCheckedListBox : CheckedListBox
{
    public event ItemCheckEventHandler ItemCheckedChanged;
    protected virtual void OnItemCheckedChanged(ItemCheckEventArgs ice)
    {
        var h = ItemCheckedChanged;
        if (h != null)
            h(this, ice);
    }

    protected override void OnItemCheck(ItemCheckEventArgs ice)
    {
        base.OnItemCheck(ice);

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback((state) =>
            {
                this.BeginInvoke(new Action<ItemCheckEventArgs>(OnItemCheckedChanged), ice);
            }));
    }
```

No you have a `ItemCheckedChanged` event that you can subscribe to.

Actually there is no need to subclass. This can be done in the form itself, but this is cleaner.

### How does it work?

The `ItemCheck` event is called inside the `SetItemCheckState` method. This method changes the check state of the item *after* calling the event (`OnItemCheck`). Also calling `SetItemCheck` is a consequence of a windows message that is passed to the message queue of the application. We want our message to be fired after this message is processed, so we have to post a new message into the queue, so that our message is processed after this message. The `BeginInvoke` method actually posts a message into the message queue, but only if called from another thread. That's why I called `BeginInvoke` in a new thread form thread pool.

Another solution to this could be registering a message and manually posting it to the message queue, but that would be a lot more code!

Answer (score 0):

Rather do the following:

```
int checkedcount = 0;
foreach(var item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems){
   if(checkedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(checkedListBox1.Items.IndexOf(item) == System.Windows.Forms.CheckState.Checked)
      checkedcount++;
}
```

For further reference look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditemcollection.aspx).